# Small icons stretching to unwanted sizes

Tags: html, css, image, stretch

Having an issue with a small 53x49 image icon being stretched to a giant size.

This:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/837/arrowsj.png/

Is supposed to be this size:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/32/resetw.png/

Does anyone know what would cause this to happen? Or what to look for to take out to prevent it? Or what to type in to fix it?

Have Tried:
Using background image, using a div.

Thanks!

Image code:

```
<a href='getestimate.php'><img id='fixed' src='css/images/reset.png' alt='Reset' title='Reset'></a>
```

CSS CODE:

```
* { padding:0; margin:0; outline:0; }
body {
background:#fff;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
line-height:18px;
color:#6d6d6d;
}
input, textarea, select { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px;color:#6d6d6d;     }

a img { border:0; display: block;}

a { color:#0184c4; text-decoration: underline; cursor:pointer; }
a:hover { color:#1c6183; text-decoration: none; }
#fixed {width:53px; height:49px;}

.notext { font-size:0; line-height:0; text-indent: -4000px; display:block; }

.left, .alignleft { float:left; display:inline; }
.right, .alignright { float:right; display:inline; }

.cl { font-size:0; line-height:0; clear:both; display:block; height:0; }

.al { text-align: left; }
.ar { text-align: right; }
.ac { text-align: center; }

h2 { font-size:23px; line-height:26px; color:#0188c9; }
h3 { font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#000; }

h2, h3 { font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;}

h1#logo { font-size:0; line-height:0; width:245px; height:74px; float:left; }
h1#logo a{ display:block; height:74px; text-indent: -4000px;     background:url(images/logo.gif); }

.shell { width:980px; margin:0 auto; }

#header { height:74px; background:url(images/header.gif);}

#navigation { float:right; height:30px;}
#navigation ul{ float:left; height:30px; list-style-type:none; padding-top:27px;}
#navigation ul li{ float:left; display:inline; margin-left:10px;}
#navigation ul li a{ float:left; width:110px; height:30px; text-align: center; background:url(images/nav.gif) no-repeat 0 0; line-height:30px; text-decoration: none; color:#7b7b7b; }

#navigation ul li a:hover,
#navigation ul li a.active { background-position:right 0; color:#fff;}

#slider { height:390px; background:url(images/slider.gif);}


.slider-holder { height:390px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; z-index:100}
.slides { width:894px; height:315px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; top:59px; left:43px;}
.slides .jcarousel-clip{ width:894px; height:315px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; }
.slides ul{ width:758px; height:315px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; list-style-type: none;}
.slides ul li{ float:left; display:inline; width:758px; height:315px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; margin:0 0 0 136px; left:-68px;}


.slide-shadow { position:absolute; bottom:0; height:26px; width:771px; background:url(images/slide-shadow.png); left:-6px;}
.slide-bg { width:758px; height:267px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; background:url(images/slide-bg.gif); padding:5px; }
.slide-image{ float:left; width:271px; }
.slide-info{ float:left; width:440px; padding:30px 0 0 15px; }
.slide-info p{ padding:13px 0 20px;}

.slider-nav { font-size:0; line-height:0; }
.slider-nav a{ width:43px; height:46px; text-indent: -4000px; position:absolute; top:165px; }
.slider-nav a.prev{ left:0; background:url(images/prev.gif); }
.slider-nav a.next{ left:937px; background:url(images/next.gif); }

.learn-button { width:165px; height:37px; background:url(images/learn-button.gif); }

#main { width:100%; background:url(images/main.gif) repeat-x 0 0; padding:45px 0 40px 0;}

.col { float:left; display:inline; width:280px; margin-right:70px; padding:10px 0;}
.col-last { margin-right:0;}

.col h3 { padding-bottom:12px; }
.col p { padding-bottom:12px; }

.three-cols { background:url(images/three-cols.gif) repeat-y center 0; width:100%;}

.ico { background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:0 1px; padding-left:26px; }
.ico1 { background-image:url(images/ico1.gif)}
.ico2 { background-image:url(images/ico2.gif)}
.ico3 { background-image:url(images/ico3.gif)}

p.more { font-size:11px; }
p.more a{ background:url(images/more.gif) no-repeat 0 center; padding-left:11px;}

#footer { height:57px; background:url(images/footer.gif); line-height:56px; white-space:nowrap; color:#5c5c5c;}
#footer span{ color:#cfcfcf; padding:0 5px;}
#footer a{ color:#5c5c5c; text-decoration: none;}
#footer a:hover{ color:#0184c4;}
```

Comment: .ge{ display: block; line-height: 0; width: 245px; height: 100px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/JhNmp/  - Fixed

Use this CSS ID

```css
#fixed {
    width:53px; 
    height:49px;
}
```

And include the ID in the html like this:

```
<img id="fixed"  etc etc etc>
```

Try this to add specificity:

```
 <div id="derp">
     <img id="fixed"  etc etc etc>
 </div>
```

and the CSS:

```css
#derp #fixed {
    width:53px; 
    height:49px;
}
```

Comment: The reason this works, by the way, is because of CSS specificity.  A CSS ID is more specific than a class and therefore cannot be over written except by something that is more specific, i.e. two ID selectors, or eleven classes.  You maybe wondering, how can you have more than one ID selector???  You can have a container div with an ID and an image inside that div with an ID and have the CSS like this:  #id1 #id2 {css styles here}.  Read up on this fantastic article to explain specificity:  http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: You may need more specificity then.  Try wrapping a div around the element with an ID of your choice and do what I suggested in the previous comment.  I'll make an example in the answer above.

Comment: Updated code to delete the ge and just do id. Even used the div. Still doesnt work.

Comment: I upvoted cmd since he has a better solution.  Your image has a class of ".ge" and if you go to your CSS file under the ".ge" class, you see that you have declared a height and width of your image.  Delete that and it should work.  If not, add the ID's.

Comment: Is it possible the javascript is affecting it somehow?

Comment: Javascript could affect it, but I doubt it.  Easy way to tell, is to disable javascript in your browser.

Comment: if you choose a phone model and hit next it pops up

Comment: just tested the js. Not that.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnagaming.net%2Ftest%2Fgetestimate.php%3Fmodel%3D4&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Check the above validator, there is an error somewhere and it is precisely on your image. Check to make sure you have all your tags properly ended.  It's something stupid like that, I'm sure.

Comment: </derp>  Here!  You closed the </div> with </derp> by accident.

Comment: LOL! Still didnt fix it. But apparently I derped there >.<

Comment: It still hasn't validated on my end, did you upload it to the server?

Comment: Okay, you fixed that, but go back to the validator.  You have a few more syntax errors to deal with.

Comment: <!---<section class="content">  This is not a comment.  A comment is both <!--  and ends with -->    fix that block over there first.

Comment: Maybe add a space if you want that commented out:

Comment: <!--- <section class="content">  -->

Comment: Line 189 of your html ....   <li><a hrerf="#">Home</a></li>   take out the > after "#"

Comment: Do that for lines 189 - 195.

Comment: Good. And the problem remains.  Okay, I'll fix this with you - no worries. But you better give me credit on the question for this!  Let's take a look at some other stuff.

Comment: .main .post img {
float : left;
margin-right : 18px;
width : 333px;
height : 333px;
}

Comment: Make the width 33px and height 33px and see if that is the selector that is causing problems

Comment: I think I may be mentally challenged. I was editing the wrong freaking css document. What a waste of everyones time.....the .post fixed it......>.< How do i up vote you?

Comment: Apparently ive been staring at code too many hours in a row. Easiest fix ever but I'm too stupid to look at the file path. Dandy!

Comment: I believe you just click the check mark on the question.  Well I'm glad you fixed it!  And lesson learned, specificity matters!  Btw, the guy below would have been right too since in line css styling is the MOST specific you can get, but it is also the worst way to do it since the whole point of CSS is to separate style from content.  So when you go to change something later, you will NEVER remember that inline styling and it will drive you crazy because it can't be out-specified.

Comment: Gave you the answer. Thanks for the help...Gonna go cry in a corner now

Comment: Hey man, it happens to ALL of us.  Someone helped me like this not too long ago and it helped me advance greatly.  I had browser cookies enabled and I kept changing and changing and realized after half a day that I probably had to delete the cache and cookies to see any changes.  That's how we learn!  Take care!

Answer (score 1):

change notext { font-size:0; line-height:0; text-indent: -4000px; display:block; to { font-size:0; line-height:0; text-indent: -400px; display:block;

ge{ display: block; line-height: 0; width: 245px; height: 100px; float: left to ge{ display: block; line-height: 0; width: 150px; height: 75px; float: left

thats really the only tweaking that you can do to change the sizes down.

sorry if im not much help to you.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than formatting with CSS, try setting the `width` and `height` values of the images. Remove the CSS class before that.
Like this...

```
<img src='css/images/reset.png' alt='Reset' title='Reset' width='53' height='49'></a>
```